# Continuous variables: Probability of outcome in a quadrature measurement

Tags: phase-space, wigner-transform, quantum-measurements

In the phase-space formulation of QM over continuous variables, how can I determine the probability of obtaining a particular measurement outcome $m$ in the following setting.

Given a quantum state $\rho$ described by the Wigner function $W_{\rho}(q,p)$, one measures the observable $\hat{p}$. What is the probability of obtaining a particular outcome $m\in\mathbb{R}$? I know that in standard QM I need to calculate 
$$\text{Tr }(\rho \; |m\rangle _p\langle m |)$$
and I have found that such expectation values, in phase space formulation, are usually computed via
$$\text{Tr }(\rho A)=\int dq dp W_{\rho}(q,p)A(q,p)$$
where $\hat{A}$ is some observable expressed as a combintation of $\hat{q}$ and $\hat{p}$.

Once this easy quadrature measurement is clarified, I would also like to understand partial measurements, i.e. let $W(q_1,p_1,q_2,p_2)$ be the input state, then what is probability of outcome $m$ when measuring $\hat{p}$ only on the first mode.

Note, I am new to the phase-space formulation. Thus, I would also appreciate a good reference where I could simply read up on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wigner map image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform#The_inverse_map) of your momentum projection operator $|m\rangle \langle m|$ is 
$$
A(q,p)= 2 \int dy ~ e^{2ipy/\hbar} \langle q+y| m\rangle \langle m|q-y\rangle =
\frac {2} { 2\pi} \int dy ~ e^{2ipy/\hbar} e^{-2imy/\hbar} = \delta (p-m),
$$
by virtue of $\langle x|p\rangle= \exp (ixp/\hbar)~/\sqrt{2\pi}$, etc.

Consequently, the expectation you presumably arrived at in your intro is 
$$
\int\! dq ~ W_\rho (q,m).
$$

Mutatis mutandis, collapsing the momentum of $\hat p _1$ to *m*, yields 
$$\int \! dq_1 dq_2 dp_2 ~ W(q_1,m,q_2,p_2).$$

Here is a concise [review](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf)  with exercises to practice on.

Comment: Great thanks. I was lacking the Wigner map ingredient. Now, things make a lot more sense. Ultimately, I would like to understand quantum teleportation in this setting. There the question came up, whether the probability of obtaining a particular outcome when working with ideal (inifinitely squeezed states) entangled resources, is actually well defined. It seems like it is uniform over the reals which makes it non-normalizable and thus not a probability distribution. Do you happen to know if this is correct? Thanks for the review, I will check it out and do some calculations myself.

Comment: I know there is a cottage industry in this. [Groenewold](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/20Groenewold46.pdf) concludes his seminal thesis paper of 1946 with such, and Bell has written an entire paper on it. But I am not familiar with the rich bibliography on the subject. Yes, sharp eigenstates of momentum or position amount to unnormalized delta function Wigner Functions.